# Running apps as root (using AppEditor)

Tags: root

I want to run Arduino IDE as root, because if I run it normally (as a normal user), it won't allow me to upload the code to the Arduino. For now I have circumvented this issue by creating a symlink to the arduino file in my installation directory (for me it is /opt/arduino-1.8.5/arduino) and running it as sudo.

I want to be able to run it from the application menu, so I used a program called AppEditor (from the AppCentre)
[image: Before]

If I add "sudo" before the "/opt/arduino-1.8.5/arduino" as listed below, the program will not even run. Am I writing the syntax wrong?
[image: After]

Answer (score 3):

`sudo` is a command-line tool, you need to use `gksudo` instead in this case as this will pop up a dialogue asking for the password.

However, this is probably not what you really want to do as it means the entire IDE is running as root which would be a security issue. What you should do is figure out what needs privileges and add your user to the correct group to enable access.

For example, wireshark/tshark need users should be added to the `wireshark` group rather than run as root. Similarly, users who need access to the serial ports should be part of the `dialout` group (maybe this is what you need).